# How do I keep a DbContext connection open when instantiating a custom object?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to instantiate a custom object that drills down a few levels on the database object and I'm getting runtime database connection errors.

In my controller class...

```
private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
...
foreach (Order thisOrder in orders) {
    CustomerActionReturnModel thisAction = new CustomerActionReturnModel(thisOrder);
    thisAction.Order.OrderItems = new List<OrderItemReturnModel>();
    foreach (OrderItem thisItem in thisOrder.OrderItems) {
        thisAction.Order.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItemReturnModel(thisItem));
    }
    thisResponse.CustomerActions.Add(thisAction);
}
...
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

In my model class

```
...
[ModelName("OrderItemReturnModel")]
public class OrderItemReturnModel {
...
public OrderItemReturnModel(OrderItem dbOrderItem) {
        OrderItemID = dbOrderItem.OrderItemID;
        PriceCharged = dbOrderItem.PriceCharged;

        if (dbOrderItem.Quantity != null) {
            Quantity = (int)dbOrderItem.Quantity;
        }

        ProductDescription = dbOrderItem.StoreProduct.Product.Description;
        ProductImageURL = dbOrderItem.StoreProduct.Product.ImageURLFormatted48;
    }
```

As you can see, I try to access

```
    dbOrderItem.StoreProduct.Product.Description;
```

and

```
dbOrderItem.StoreProduct.Product.ImageURLFormatted48;
```

And it doesn't like it

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.", 
"ExceptionMessage": "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.", 
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
```

Is there any way I can keep my dbContext open while I'm constructing my OrderItemReturnModel?

Comment: Do you create some tasks or extra threads? Because it looks like you trying to access dbContext after controller was disposed.

Comment: well, I'm guess that dbContext is disposed "temporarily"? when I instantiate the OrderItemReturnModel.  Not really sure I understand what EF is doing with it.  I'm able to access top level dbObject properties, but not 2nd or 3rd level.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you are using ASP.NET since you mention **"in my controller"**, so please don't use a controller-level db context.

Doing that in a multi threaded environment like asp.net will lead you to soo many problems.

The recommended approach is to create an instance of DbContext wherever you need it inside an using statement:

In your controller (or better yet, in a service class, repository or business manager):

```
using (var db = new MyEntities()){
        //use db to fetch orders 
        foreach (Order thisOrder in orders) {
            CustomerActionReturnModel thisAction = new CustomerActionReturnModel(thisOrder);
            thisAction.Order.OrderItems = new List<OrderItemReturnModel>();
            foreach (OrderItem thisItem in thisOrder.OrderItems) {
                thisAction.Order.OrderItems.Add(new OrderItemReturnModel(thisItem));
            }
         thisResponse.CustomerActions.Add(thisAction);
        }
}
```

DbContext is designed to be short-lived object and declaring it as member variable will not provide you with better performance but the opposite.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. People keep trying to reuse connections in ADO, Linq, EF declaring db context as member variable. That's a dangerous thing to do in asp.net.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but just FYI, I'm handling that with the "Dispose" method in the controller.  Plus, this error occurs when using the "using" method as well.

Comment: @Jarrette No problem. I never said it was you. Is just that people down vote an don't make any useful comment about it. That's a little frustrating. If I can be of any help just let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I think people love to downvote, it's frustrating.  Thanks for trying to help.